# My program segfaults when I try to copy a row from one 2D dynamic array to another

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

The whole program is meant to decode a text input coded in column cipher (dunno how to say it in english, you just swap columns in two 2D array after you enter the text and read it ).
Two 2D dynamic arrays are declared properly and work just fine till I try to assign value from one to the another ( they have same dimensions )

After hour of debugging I know that line  "result[row][line] = txt[key[row]][line]" segfaults . If change to for example "result[row][line] = 'b'" the dynamic array result gets filled with b's as it should. 
But to complete my assigment I need to decode the message ! So I've got to put in result's first row the row from txt array . The first element of key array says which row of txt array should be copied to result's array first row, and then second etc.

```
void decipher ( char **txt, char **result, char *key, int rowNumber, int  lineNumber)
{


int line = 0;
int row = 0 ;
do{
    if(line == lineNumber) break;
    if(row == rowNumber) {
            row  = 0; line;
    }
    result[row][line] = txt[key[row]][line];  //Segfault HERE !
    ++row;
}while(true) ;
```

}

Comment: The key array is properly sized?

Comment: What is `row  = 0; line;` supposed to do ?

Comment: What's the value of `key[row]`? Are you sure it's a valid index in `txt`? (BTW: I have a feeling that `line;` is missing a "++" or something.)

Comment: indeed line was missing ++ , good eye ! :) the key array has the same length as rowNumber. Each value of key[x] indicates which row/column of txt array should be copied to x row/column of result array. Value of key[row] cannot possibly exceed the indexes of txt. I input the key using keyboard.

Comment: BTW: there was no missing ++ in program code, I just pasted it wrong. There is still segfault.